# Apache2, Wordpress index.php not executed, just text file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a problem with apache2, wordpress and php.
I configured virtual hosts and copied the existing wordpress (installed in single host).
The web server is working fine and loads the index.php, but doesn't execute it.

Comment: that means your server ISN'T working fine, and you haven't configured php properly, so .php files are being served up as plain text.

Comment: I recommend you change your database username and password as it is viewable to everyone here since you posted the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Check mod-enabled folder in your apache. You must have two files their php5.load and php5.conf. If not present, its means php support is not their.To enable php support use command `a2enmod php5`

Answer (score 0):

It is because your apache2 can't execute php.
In my case, I install *libapache2-mod-php* by:

`aptitude install libapache2-mod-php7.0`

Then restart apache by:

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

May it help you.